# "sorted 1-d iterator" based on "2-d iterator" (Cartesian product of iterators)

Tags: python, iterator

I'm looking for a clean way to do this in Python:

Let's say I have two iterators "iter1" and "iter2": perhaps a prime number generator, and itertools.count().  I know a priori that both are are infinite and monotonically increasing.  Now I want to take some simple operation of two args "op" (perhaps operator.add or operator.mul), and calculate **every element** of the first iterator with **every element** of the next, using said operation, then yield them one at a time, sorted.  Obviously, this is an infinite sequence itself.  (As mentioned in comment by @RyanThompson: this would be called the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of these sequences... or, more exactly, the 1d-sort of that product.)

What is the best way to:

- wrap-up "iter1", "iter2", and "op" in an iterable that itself yields the values in monotonically increasing output.

Allowable simplifying assumptions:

- If it helps, we can assume op(a,b) >= a and op(a,b) >= b.
- If it helps, we can assume op(a,b) > op(a,c) for all b > c.

Also allowable:

- Also acceptable would be an iterator that yields values in "generally increasing" order... by which I mean the iterable could occasionally give me a number less than a previous one, but it would somehow make "side information" available (as via a method on the object) that would say "I'm not guarenteeing the next value I give you will be greater than the one I just gave you, but I AM SURE that all future values will at least be greater than N.".... and "N" itself is monotonically increasing.

The only way I can think to do this is a sort of "diagonalization" process, where I keep an increasing number of partially processed iterables around, and "look ahead" for the minimum of all the possible next() values, and yield that.  But this weird agglomeration of a heapq and a bunch of deques just seems outlandish, even before I start to code it.

Please: do *not* base your answer on the fact that my examples mentioned primes or count().... I have several uses for this very concept that are NOT related to primes and count().

---

**UPDATE:** OMG! What a great discussion!  And some great answers with really thorough explanations.  Thanks so much.  StackOverflow rocks; you guys rock.

I'm going to delve in to each answer more thoroughly soon, and give the sample code a kick in the tires.  From what I've read so far, my original suspicions are confirmed that there is no "simple Python idiom" to do this.  Rather, by one way or another, I can't escape keeping all yielded values of iter1 and iter2 around indefinitely.

FWIW: here's an official "test case" if you want to try your solutions.

```
import operator

def powers_of_ten():
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield 10**n
        n += 1

def series_of_nines():
    yield 1
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield int("9"*n)
        n += 1

op = operator.mul
iter1 = powers_of_ten()
iter2 = series_of_nines()

# given (iter1, iter2, op), create an iterator that yields:
# [1, 9, 10, 90, 99, 100, 900, 990, 999, 1000, 9000, 9900, 9990, 9999, 10000, ...]
```

Comment: So then a merge sort of infinite sequences?

Comment: I have a bad English, but do you want something like "for i in (operator.add(i,j) for i,j in zip (range(10),range(10))): print(i)
"?

Comment: No, sorry.  The "zip" in your example keeps i=j.  I want something like this: `operator.add(a, b) for all a in iter1() for all b in iter2()`... and I want them sorted (low to high) as they are yielded.

Comment: Is assuming op(b,a) > op(c,a) for all b > c also allowed? (Is op(a,b) = op(b,a) like for add&mul?)

Comment: @Dan H: You totally overgeneralized the question. If `op` is `(+)` then the diagonalization algorithm you outlined would work. On the other hand, if you merge with `lambda *args:random.choice(args)` then you have no chance to merge at all ... Ask your real problem.

Comment: You can just use a generator and return `a + b` after getting the next value of `iter1()` and `iter2()` (where `a` = next value of `iter1()` and `b` = next value of `iter2()`). This is easy to do if you write `iter1()` and `iter2()` as generators.

Comment: @Jochen: agreed. @Dan: can you give more examples of how you will use this?

Comment: The easiest example would be to list a multiplication table in ascending order, if I understand correctly. In mathematical terms, the OP wants to apply a function to every element of the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the iterators, and then sort the result.

Comment: @BaffeBoyois: yes, you can assume that relationship for b > c, too.

Comment: @RyanThompson: **that's** the term I was looking for: _"Cartesian Product"_.

Comment: @Jochen: iter1 = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ...], iter2 = [1, 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999]... op = operator.mul.  The output sequence I want: [1, 9, 10, 90, 99, 100, 900, 990, 999, 1000, 9000, 9900, 9990, 9999, 10000, ....]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import heapq
import itertools
import operator


def increasing(fn, left, right):
    """
    Given two never decreasing iterators produce another iterator
    resulting from passing the value from left and right to fn.
    This iterator should also be never decreasing.
    """
    # Imagine an infinite 2D-grid.
    # Each column corresponds to an entry from right
    # Each row corresponds to an entry from left
    # Each cell correspond to apply fn to those two values

    # If the number of columns were finite, then we could easily solve
    # this problem by keeping track of our current position in each column
    # in each iteration, we'd take the smallest value report it, and then
    # move down in that column. This works because the values must increase
    # as we move down the column. That means the current set of values
    # under consideration must include the lowest value not yet reported

    # To extend this to infinite columns, at any point we always track a finite
    # number of columns. The last column current tracked is always in the top row
    # if it moves down from the top row, we add a new column which starts at the top row
    # because the values are increasing as we move to the right, we know that
    # this last column is always lower then any columns that come after it





    # Due to infinities, we need to keep track of all
    # items we've ever seen. So we put them in this list
    # The list contains the first part of the incoming iterators that
    # we have explored
    left_items = [next(left)]
    right_items = [next(right)]

    # we use a heap data structure, it allows us to efficiently
    # find the lowest of all value under consideration
    heap = []

    def add_value(left_index, right_index):
        """
        Add the value result from combining the indexed attributes
        from the two iterators. Assumes that the values have already
        been copied into the lists
        """
        value = fn( left_items[left_index], right_items[right_index] )
        # the value on the heap has the index and value.
        # since the value is first, low values will be "first" on the heap
        heapq.heappush( heap, (value, left_index, right_index) )

    # we know that every other value must be larger then 
    # this one. 
    add_value(0,0)

    # I assume the incoming iterators are infinite
    while True:
        # fetch the lowest of all values under consideration
        value, left_index, right_index = heapq.heappop(heap)

        # produce it
        yield value

        # add moving down the column
        if left_index + 1 == len(left_items):
            left_items.append(next(left))

        add_value(left_index+1, right_index)

        # if this was the first row in this column, add another column
        if left_index == 0:
            right_items.append( next(right) )
            add_value(0, right_index+1)






def fib():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b,a+b



r = increasing(operator.add, fib(), itertools.count() )
for x in range(100):
    print next(r)
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer, only with code, so it's better.

Comment: This doesn't always work because you don't know that when you generate the next column the first value will be >= the previous column's first value. e.g. the first grid of outputs can look like this: `[[1,666,5],[666,666,666],[666,666,666],[666,666,666]]`. you only know `op(a,b)` > `op(a,c)` if `b>c`, you don't know that `op(g,i)`>`op(h,i)` if `g>h`. all you know is `op(a,b)>=a` and `op(a,b)>=b`, or `min(a,b)<=op(a,b)`, which is what I was getting at in my answer. so you have to generate columns until the leftmost input into the op is >= the value you want to yield.

Comment: it is a great solution if that were true, but until then it is misleading.. unless you return some value of `N` like the OP suggested - i think that's probably the best solution (yours + returning `N`)

Comment: @Claudiu, I was thinking that the f(a,b) = f(b,a) but yeah I can't actually assume that.

Comment: Ding, ding, ding!  Definitely a winner.  Worked first try on my [late-added] test case involving `powers_of_ten()` and `series_of_nines()`.  Thanks, Winston!

Answer (score 4):

Define the sequences as:

```
a1 <= a2 <= a3 ...
b1 <= b2 <= b3 ...
```

Let `a1b1` mean `op(a1,b1)` for short.

Based on your allowable assumptions (very important) you know the following:

```
max(a1, b1) <= a1b1 <= a1b2 <= a1b3 ...
   <=
max(a2, b1) <= a2b1 <= a2b2 <= a2b3 ...
   <=
max(a3, b1) <= a3b1 <= a3b2 <= a3b3 ...
    .     .
    .      .
    .       .
```

You'll have to do something like:

Generate `a1b1`. You know that if you continue increasing the `b` variables, you will only get higher values. The question now is: is there a smaller value by increasing the `a` variables? Your lower bound is `min(a1, b1)`, so you will have to increase the `a` values until `min(ax,b1) >= a1b1`. Once you hit that point, you can find the smallest value from `anb1` where `1 <= n <= x` and yield that safely.

You then will have multiple horizontal chains that you'll have to keep track of. Every time you have a value that goes past `min(ax,b1)`, you'll have to increase `x` (adding more chains) until `min(ax,b1)` is larger than it before safely emitting it.

Just a starting point... I don't have time to code it at the moment.

EDIT: Oh heh that's exactly what you already had. Well, without more info, this is all you can do, as I'm pretty sure that mathematically, that's what is necessary.

EDIT2: As for your 'acceptable' solution: you can just yield `a1bn` in increasing order of `n`, returning `min(a1,b1)` as `N` =P. You'll need to be more specific. You speak as if you have a heuristic of what you generally want to see, the general way you want to progress through both iterables, but without telling us what it is I don't know how one could do better.

---

UPDATE: Winston's is good but makes an assumption that the poster didn't mention: that `op(a,c)` > `op(b,c)` if `b>a`. However, we do know that `op(a,b)>=a` and `op(a,b)>=b`.

Here is my solution which takes that second assumption but not the one Winston took. Props to him for the code structure, though:

```
def increasing(fn, left, right):
    left_items = [next(left)]
    right_items = [next(right)]

    #columns are (column value, right index)
    columns = [(fn(left_items[0],right_items[0]),0)]

    while True:
        #find the current smallest value
        min_col_index = min(xrange(len(columns)), key=lambda i:columns[i][0])

        #generate columns until it's impossible to get a smaller value
        while right_items[0] <= columns[min_col_index][0] and \
              left_items[-1] <= columns[min_col_index][0]:
            next_left = next(left)

            left_items.append(next_left)
            columns.append((fn(next_left, right_items[0]),0))

            if columns[-1][0] < columns[min_col_index][0]:
                min_col_index = len(columns)-1

        #yield the smallest value
        yield columns[min_col_index][0]

        #move down that column
        val, right_index = columns[min_col_index]

        #make sure that right value is generated:
        while right_index+1 >= len(right_items):
            right_items.append(next(right))

        columns[min_col_index] = (fn(left_items[min_col_index],right_items[right_index+1]),
                                  right_index+1)
        #repeat
```

For a (pathological) input that demonstrates the difference, consider:

```
def pathological_one():
    cur = 0
    while True:
        yield cur
        cur += 100

def pathological_two():
    cur = 0
    while True:
        yield cur
        cur += 100

lookup = [
    [1,   666, 500],
    [666, 666, 666],
    [666, 666, 666],
    [666, 666, 666]]

def pathological_op(a, b):
    if a >= 300 or b >= 400: return 1005
    return lookup[b/100][a/100]

r = increasing(pathological_op, pathological_one(), pathological_two())
for x in range(15):
    print next(r)
```

Winston's answer gives:

```
>>> 
1
666
666
666
666
500
666
666
666
666
666
666
1005
1005
1005
```

While mine gives:

```
>>> 
1
500
666
666
666
666
666
666
666
666
666
666
1005
1005
1005
```

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to take two monotonically increasing sequences, and then (lazily) compute the multiplication (or addition, or another operation) table between them, which is a 2-D array. Then you want to put the elements of that 2-D array in sorted order and iterate through them.

In general, this is impossible. However, if your sequences and operation are such that you can make certain guarantees about the rows and columns of the table, then you can make some progress. For example, let's assume that your sequences are monitonically-increasing sequences of positive integers only, and that the operation is multiplication (as in your example). In this case, we know that every row and column of the array is a monotonically-increasing sequence. In this case, you do not need to compute the entire array, but rather only parts of it. Specifically, you must keep track of the following:

- How many rows you have ever used
- The number of elements you have taken from each row that you have used
- Every element from either input sequence that you have ever used, plus one more from each

To compute the next element in your iterator, you must do the following:

- For each row that you have ever used, compute the "next" value in that row. For example, if you have used 5 values from row 1, then compute the 6th value (i=1, j=6) by taking the 1st value from the first sequence and the 6th value from the second sequence (both of which you have cached) and applying the operation (multiplication) to them. Also, compute the first value in the first unused row.
- Take the minimum of all the values you computed. Yield this value as the next element in your iterator
- Increment the counter for the row from which you sampled the element in the previous step. If you took the element from a new, unused row, you must increment the count of the number of rows you have used, and you must create a new counter for that row initialized to 1. If necessary, you must also compute more values of one or both input sequences.

This process is kind of complex, and in particular notice that to compute N values, you must in the worst case save an amount of state proportional to the <strike>square root of</strike> N. (Edit: sqrt(N) is actually the *best* case.) This is in stark contrast to a typical generator, which only requires constant space to iterate through its elements regardless of length.

In summary, you can do this under certain assumptions, and you can provide a generator-like interface to it, but it cannot be done in a "streaming" fashion, because you need to save a lot of state in order to iterate through the elements in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks; great analysis, and thanks for commenting on the other posters, too.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with an example of how I would solve this intuitively.

Because reading code inline is a little tedious, I'll introduce some notation:

## Notation

- *i1* will represent `iter1`. *i1*<sub>0</sub> will represent the first element of `iter1`. Same for `iter2`.
- ※ will represent the `op` operator

## Intuitive solution

By using simplifying assumption 2, we know that *i1*<sub>0</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>0</sub> is the smallest element that will ever be yielded from your final iterator. The next element would the smaller of *i1*<sub>0</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>1</sub> and *i1*<sub>1</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>0</sub>.

Assuming *i1*<sub>0</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>1</sub> is smaller, you would yield that element. Next, you would yield the smaller of *i1*<sub>1</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>0</sub>, *i1*<sub>1</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>0</sub>, and *i1*<sub>1</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>1</sub>.

## Expression as traversal of a DAG

What you have here is a graph traversal problem. First, think of the problem as a tree. The root of the tree is *i1*<sub>0</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>0</sub>. This node, and each node below it, has two children. The two children of *i1*<sub>x</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>y</sub> are the following: One child is *i1*<sub>x+1</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>y</sub>, and the other child is *i1*<sub>x</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>y+1</sub>. Based on your second assumption, we know that *i1*<sub>x</sub> ※ *i2*<sub>y</sub> is less than both of its children.

(In fact, as Ryan mentions in a comment, this is a directed acyclic graph, or DAG. Some "parents" share "children" with other "parent" nodes.)

Now, we need to keep a *frontier* - a collection of nodes that could be next to be returned. After returning a node, we add both its children to the frontier. To select the next node to visit (and return from your new iterator), we compare the values of all the nodes in the frontier. We take the node with the smallest value and we return it. Then, we again add both of its child nodes to the frontier. If the child is already in the frontier (added as the child of some other parent), just ignore it.

## Storing the frontier

Because you are primarily interested in the value of the nodes, it makes sense to store these nodes indexed by value. As such, it may be in your interest to use a `dict`. Keys in this dict should be the values of nodes. Values in this dict should be lists containing individual nodes. Because the only identifying information in a node is the pair of operands, you can store individual nodes as a two-tuple of operands.

In practice, after a few iterations, your frontier may look like the following:

```
>>> frontier
{1: [(2, 3), (2, 4)], 2: [(3, 5), (5, 4)], 3: [(1, 6)], 4: [(6, 3)]}
```

## Other implementation notes

Because iterators don't support random access, you'll need to hang on to values that are produced by your first two iterators until they are no longer needed. <strike>You'll know that a value is still needed if it is referenced by any value in your frontier. You'll know that a value is no longer needed once all nodes in the frontier reference values later/greater than one you've stored. For example, *i1*<sub>20</sub> is no longer needed when nodes in your frontier reference only *i1*<sub>21</sub>, *i1*<sub>25</sub>, *i1*<sub>33</sub>, ...</strike>

As mentioned by Ryan, each value from each iterator will be used an infinite number of times. Thus, every value produced will need to be saved.

## Not practical

Unfortunately, in order to assure that elements are returned only in increasing order, the frontier will grow without bound. Your memoized values will <strike>probably also take a significant amount of space</strike> also grow without bound. This may be something you can address by making your problem less general, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: You have to hang on to every value from both iterators. You can never throw any of them away, at least not permanently, because each value from each iterator will be used an infinite number of times.

Comment: After a moment of reflection, it seems you're right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Also, wouldn't you have to maintain the frontier on a DAG, not a tree? For instance, i1_2※*i2*_2 is a child of both i1_1※i2_2 and i1_2※i2_1

Comment: the next element isnt necessarily a2*b1 or a1*b2. a3*b1 can be smaller than a1*b2, so can a4*b1, a5*b1, etc. take a look at my answer

Comment: @Wesley: Thanks for your input!  And you win the award for "Best use of the `※` character I've seen in a long time."  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [generators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators), which are just iterators written as functions that yield results. In this case you can write generators for `iter1` and `iter2` and another generator to wrap them and yield their results (or do calculations with them, or the history of their results) as you go.

From my reading of the question you want something like this, which will *calculate every element of the first iterator with every element of the next, using said operation*, you also state you want some way to *wrap-up "iter1", "iter2", and "op" in an iterable that itself yields the values in monotonically increasing output*. I propose generators offer a simple solution to such problem.

```
import itertools

def prime_gen():
    D, q = {}, 2
    while True:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]
        q += 1

def infinite_gen(op, iter1, iter2):
    while True:
        yield op(iter1.next(), iter2.next())

>>> gen = infinite_gen(operator.mul, prime_gen(), itertools.count())

>>> gen.next()
<<< 0

>>> gen.next()
<<< 3

>>> gen.next()
<<< 10
```

Generators offer a lot of flexibility, so it should be fairly easy to write `iter1` and `iter2` as generators that return values you want in the order you want. You could also consider using [coroutines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), which let you send values *into* a generator.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for.  If I can use a sequence notation, what you gave me is: yield primes[i]+count[i] for all i.... which is a "one dimensional" output.   What I'm looking for is yield primes[i]+count[j] for all i,j , sorted lowest to highest.

Comment: what do you mean for all i,j? Can you provide some sample output?

Comment: Do you just want prime and count to start on different numbers? I updated my answer to reflect that. Not sure I understand what you want but you can just wrap a prime function and a count function in another function, pass it the arguments, have it call count/prime differently.

Comment: @Dan H generators are pretty flexible, if you can provide an example of output you'd like I can rewrite the function to suit.

Comment: @zeekay: read the question: "Please: do not base your answer on the fact that my examples mentioned primes or count().... I have several uses for this very concept that are NOT related to primes and count().". the functions might be different and your code assumes things that aren't true with the generic function he's looking for

Comment: @Claudiu I illustrate a generic usage at the end of my answer where you would pass a generator the operators required as well as the iterators, and it will yield "every element of the first iterator with every element of the next, using said operation." Admittedly, I don't understand wtf he wants. And I've asked for clarification of the proposed output of the function, so I could rewrite the generator function appropriately. In my view generators are flexible enough that my example can be adapted to his usage.

Comment: @Claudiu I tried to clarify my answer, if you can offer some insight into what the OP's function is expected to return, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you only yield `op(a1,b1)`,`op(a2,b2)`,`op(a3,b3)`, etc. the op wants `op(a1,b1)`, `op(a1,b2)`,`op(a1,b3`),...,`op(a2,b1)`,`op(a2,b2)`,...,etc. see my answer for a clearer picture. for example, if given input `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[5,6,7,8,9]`, you should yield 25 values, but you only yield 5.

Comment: @Claudiu so it should yield `[op(a1,b1),op(a2,b1)]` then `[op(a1,b2),op(a2,b2)]` followed by `[op(a1,b3),op(a2,b3)]`? Or does it literally yield an infinite sequence of `op(a1,b1), op(a1,b2),op(a1,b3),etc` and at some indeterminate time increment a and start yielding op(a2,b1),op(a2,b2)?

Comment: @zeekay: that's the hard part. it has to yield all the possible combinations, but in increasing order.

Comment: @Claudiu ah! I see, thus the use of `heapq`, in the [Winston Hewit's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938309/sorted-1-d-iterator-based-on-2-d-iterator/5942043#5942043) answer, which is a perfect fit for this situation.

Comment: @Claudiu Why almost? It seems pretty simple, just keep `heappush`'ing new values in to the list as you iterate through the iterators and and `heappop` off the lowest value.

Answer (score 0):

Discussion in other answers observes that there is potentially infinite storage required no matter what the algorithm, since every `a[n]` must remain available for each new `b[n]`.  If you remove the restriction that the *input* be two iterators and instead only require that they be sequences (indexable or merely something that can be regenerated repeatedly) then I believe all of your state suddenly collapses to one number:  The last value you returned.  Knowing the last result value you can search the output space looking for the next one.  (If you want to emit duplicates properly then you may need to also track the number of times the result has been returned)

With a pair of sequences you have a simple recurrence relation:

```
result(n) = f(seq1, seq1, result(n-1))
```

where `f(seq1, seq1, p)` searches for the minimum value in the output space `q` such that `q > p`.  In practical terms you'd probably make the sequences memoized functions and choose your search algorithm to avoid thrashing the pool of memoized items.